# Semantic security and indistinguishability

Tags: semantic-security

I have two frames `f1` and `f2` that are each composed of several elements noted `e`. Note that, an element can fall into one of those two categories: an identifier or a counter.

What I want is to find a property that verifies indistinguishability of elements between frames. For instance, given the element `e` as an identifier, if `f1.e==f2.e` the property is not verified while it is verified if `f1.e!=f2.e`.

For now, I only suppose that such a property includes probabilities and can be obtained via:

1. semantically secure block cipher for identifier elements;
2. PRNG for counter elements.

Comment: What's a 'frame'?  Sounds specific. I.e. is this a maths or computer science question?

Comment: @PaulUszak : A frame is a sequence of bytes. For instance, the hexadecimal representation of a frame can be `0x1242338455667798f1eeaa...`. The question can be seen as a math question applied to computer science :).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Format Preserving Encryption for either one of the elements. FPE will create a *keyed permuation* for a specific domain (presuming that this domain can be practically converted to a number representation). That way your identifier can just be a sequential number.

You could see a block cipher as an FPE for a specific domain with $2^n$ elements, where $n$ is the block size in bits. If you can define your domain to have that many elements (even unused ones) then yes, you could use a block cipher. This could be an issue if you cannot handle a relatively large output size (you cannot store $2^{32}$ bits or more, for instance).

You can also create a random nonce, but due to the birthday problem, you will have to generate a pretty large value to avoid collisions in the element itself (and, of course, the encrypted element as well).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how can I translate elements of your answer into a formal/mathematical definition including probabilities ?

Comment: Probabilities of what exactly?

Comment: For instance, the probability of the field `e` of `f2` not to be the same as `e` of `f1`. The point is that I don't know how to formalize it with mathematical formulas...

Comment: If the input is unique then the output is also unique for format preserving encryption. So $e \neq e' \to E(e) \neq E(e')$. The probability is zero as it is a permutation. You can only get collisions when using the same input or when using a different key.